# GPS running in background when Here Drive+ is running

Tags: windows-phone-8, gps, geolocation, here-api

i have a problem running my wp (8.0) app properly in the background when HERE Drive+ is running in the foreground. my app is a location based app.

i've setup a little demo project to reproduce and isolate and simplify the problem.

I have a GeoLocator, which is checking and displaying the current location in the PositionChanged event to a label, when in foreground. when running in background, it displays a toast every 5 seconds (to show me, that the PositionChanged event is still triggered).

pretty forward stuff, that works.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        App.LocationWatcher.ReportInterval = 5000;
        App.LocationWatcher.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
        App.LocationWatcher.PositionChanged += LocationWatcherOnPositionChanged;
        App.LocationWatcher.StatusChanged += LocationWatcherOnStatusChanged;
    }

    private void LocationWatcherOnStatusChanged(Geolocator sender, StatusChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        DisplayToast("Status:", args.Status.ToString());
    }

    private void LocationWatcherOnPositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!App.IsRunningInBackground)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
                this.tbkLastUpdatedValue.Text = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
                this.tbkLatitudeValue.Text = args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
                this.tbkLongitudeValue.Text = args.Position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayToast("Location:", args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString());
        }
    }
```

So, now the problem: When my app runs in background, it displays it's toasts, when i run any other app (including the normal map, which actually uses gps), but when i run HERE Drive+, my PositionChanged and my StatusChanged events dont get triggered anymore.

there is an app on the marketplace that is capable to run in background when here drive+ is running in foreground, as [stated in the marketplace comments](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/store/apps/poibase-mobile/9wzdncrdfwvs) (in german only)

any ideas how to solve this or what may cause that problem?

Comment: Two ideas: 
1st: Did you try compiling against Windows 8.1 RT?
2nd: Are you sure your app is still running in background? HERE Drive+ may consumes too much memory so your application could be suspended when you start/use it.

Comment: 1st: Can you further explain, what you mean by that? i have a wp8.0 project. 2nd: I'm not really sure. Any user entered data is persisted in the UI when i return to my app, but i can see that the Application_Deactivated event of my app is getting triggered when i open HERE Drive+

Comment: 1st: Maybe your application behaves differenty when you upgrade it to a WinPhone 8.1 project. Maybe it's working properly then.

2nd: Do you restore the data in the activated event?  May be your app has been tombstoned (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). In that case you don't receive any positioning information in background. Windows Phone closes background apps when there is not enough RAM left.

Comment: 1st: Tried that, but the problem remains. 2nd: No, i'm not restoring the data actively. afaik any data should be gone when the app was tombstoned, if i dont persist it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows SDK is no longer. An alternative could be to use the HERE Maps API for Javascript, which supports vector map data rendering.